# Why is my Javascript parent scope overridden when declaring a subclass?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, scope

I have two javascript classes, one inheriting from the from the other, declared as such:

```
var Sup = (function(){
    var self;

    var sup = function(){
        self = this;
        self.type = 'Sup';
    };

    sup.prototype.getType = function(){
        return self.type;
    };

    return sup;
})();

var Sub = (function(){
    var self;

    var sub = function(){
        self = this;
        Sup.call(self);
        self.type = 'Sub';
    };

    sub.prototype = Object.create(Sup.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;

    return sub;
})();
```

When I am instantiating Sub, it overrides the `self` value in its parent class:

```
var sup = new Sup();
var sub = new Sub();
console.log(sup.getType());
console.log(sub.getType());
```

yields

```
Sub // I expected Sup
Sub
```

---

I have two questions:

- Why is that? I thought `self`, as declared in `Sup`, would act as a private variable tied to each instance of `Sup`.
- I like the feeling of tidiness I get when enclosing all of the class definition in a `(function(){...})`, but when I do that I need the `self` variable to access the class scope when declaring private methods.

  For example:

  ```
  var Sup = (function(){
      //...
      function _getType(){
          return self.type; // 'this.type' is undefined here
      }
  })();
  ```

  Can I solve that problem while keeping the enclosing `(function(){})()` structure?

---

**EDIT: answer to how to call (what I called) a "private" method**

In `_getType`, `this` would refer to `Sup` and not the object being created (`sup` for example), so this solves my issue:

```
var Sup = (function(){
    var sup = function(){
        this.type = 'Sup';
    };

    sup.prototype.callPrivateGetType = function(){
        return _getType(this);
    };

    function _getType(that){
        return that.type;
    }
}
```

Then doing

```
var sup = new Sup();
var sub = new Sub();
console.log(sup.callPrivateGetType());
console.log(sub.callPrivateGetType());
```

yields

```
Sup
Sub
```

Comment: When `Sub` calls `Sup.call(self)`, `this` in `Sup` is the same as `self` in `Sub`. There's just one object, not two objects, and it can only have one `type` property.

Comment: "*a private variable tied to each instance of Sup.*" - No. Given that it's declared outside of the constructor, it's not much more than a **static** "private" variable which holds the last constructed instance.

Comment: @Barmar @Bergi: thanks, I think I was mixing up the instance object with its factory - `sup` being the instance and `Sup` the factory, `self` refers to the `Sup`. Then if I remove the `self`, which is not doing what I thought it was, how else can get access to the object being created from the factory, like in the `_getType()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not a "private variable", nor are these "classes" - because JavaScript has neither. You can informally talk about private variables or classes, but forgetting that those concepts do not carry over from other languages perfectly is quite dangerous, as you experienced here.

`self` is a local variable that is closed over by `getType` method. Evaluation goes like this:

- Evaluating the IIFE on the right side of the `Sup` assignment:
- `self` is a local variable (let's call it `SupSelf`)
- `sup` constructor is defined
- `getType` method is attached to it; `getType` function is a closure, closing over `SupSelf`
- `sup` prototype gets returned from IIFE, and assigned to `Sup`.

When you call `sub.getType()`:

- set `this` to `sub`, and evaluate `Sup.prototype.getType`:
- inside `getType`, `self` is the closed-over `SupSelf`, which got the value `Sup` assigned to it by `new Sup()`. It cannot read the value `self` inside `Sub`, as it is not local to it.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, that helps. However, I don't see why instantiating a new `sub = new Sub()` overrides `SupSelf` in the *original* object `sup = new Sup()`, which seems to me should be unrelated.

Comment: Ah, that's what the problem is. Yes, `Sup.call(SubSelf)` does in fact set `SupSelf` to `SubSelf`; given that `self` is not an "instance variable" but a "class variable" (for familiarity's sake), both of them print `SupSelf`, which has been assigned to be `Sub` by the latest call (`new Sub()`), overwriting what the previous call (`new Sup()`) set there. There is only one `SupSelf` and one `SubSelf`, not one per object.

Comment: I see the distinction now, that makes sense. I think I understand then how to use my private method `_getType` - just pass the "instance" scope as a parameter, since `this` would refer to the "class". Thanks !

Comment: By the way... you can do simply `sub.constructor`, and if you need the name, if you change `var sub = function()...` into `var sub = function Sub()...`, you can do `sub.constructor.name` - no need for this headache :P

Comment: Yes the `type` property was really just an example to understand here :) Thanks for the tip!